# How is (Server-Side Swift framework) Vapor 3.0 vs 2.0 doing performance-wise? Is it anything serious other than for small-scale projects?

Tags: swift, vapor

Compared to 2.0, to Perfect, or Python franeworks like Django. If usable for anything than small scale projects

Comment: This question looks subjective, broad, probably debatable too, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I'll assume your question is as follows:

> What does Vapor 3's architectural changes mean for performance and larger projects?

I'll leave specific hard numbers to other frameworks out of this discussion.

---

Vapor 3 is a framework that is designed for the future. It's extremely performant, lightweight on memory usage, scalable and has a large officially supported feature set.

---

## Performance

Whilst these are **not** hard numbers, my laptop measures the [HTTP Engine](https://github.com/vapor/engine/) at 103k plaintext requests/second.

The [Vapor framework](https://github.com/vapor/vapor/) is a little lower because of the overhead in the default middlewares, the Service and Content systems. It's still really performant with a plaintext throughput of 80k requests/second.

## Memory usage

Vapor 3's memory overhead on boot is in my tests between 6.4MB and 7.5MB. This is in line with the Go frameworks I tested.

## Scalable

Vapor 3's main architectural difference is key here. We've worked on our own [Async library](https://github.com/vapor/async) that is inspired by [reactive-streams.org](http://reactive-streams.org) from the Java ecosystem. Our stream model is a pull-stream model, where data is not forced upon another library, but a library requests more data when ready. Because this is applied throughout our entire ecosystem, memory usage stays really low, regardless of the size of the requests. The few exceptions to this rule are (Multipart) forms, JSON and Templating. Templating is the only library where we will be able to apply proper reactiveness in the future.

## Features

Besides reactiveness in the Web Framework we've also built out our own [ORM, Fluent.](https://github.com/vapor/fluent)

Fluent supports SQLite by default, but also has drivers for [MySQL](https://github.com/vapor/mysql), [PostgreSQL](https://github.com/vapor/postgresql) and [MongoDB through MongoKitten](https://github.com/OpenKitten/MongoKitten).

In addition to these drivers we've also got support for [Redis](https://github.com/vapor/redis).

All of the above drivers support reactive streams and Codable. The drivers are written in Swift without a C library underneath and are highly optimized for reduced memory copies.

## Integration

Because we built and maintain the entire ecosystem described above, we're able to achieve a deeper integration in both performance and APIs than most other frameworks. This does, however, have a significant impact on the size of our workload.

## Future Proof

We decided to make most of our APIs internal until demand has been made clear of a feature being publicly accessible. This is done to ensure chages to our implementations do not cause breaking changes.

## Is it usable for medium/large scale projects?

I'm not able to be the judge of that. I'm a member of the Vapor 3 core team. However, we've got an active slack community that is able to tell you their experiences using Vapor 3 so far. We're still in beta, so I wouldn't release a product with it just yet.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this elaborate answer. (I upvoted it but it said it might not show because I'm a new user). Do you know how it compares to Perfect in terms of performance? (2.0 used to perform much worse according to benchmarks, which are what they are). I find it super cool that it be written entirely in Swift, but perhaps the absence of C for highly solicitated parts may be what limits it so much performance-wise. Do you think the stance on this could change and that some C might be used in the future?

Comment: "Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Comment: Vapor 3 relies heavily on Swift. Swift is not a bottleneck at all. Vapor 3 is completely written in Swift and outperforms even Go frameworks.

Comment: Swift is a great language, and most of the performance relies on the structure, but C still allows to write programs that execute more efficiently. How much does Vapor 3.0 impact latency? (Vapor has high latency compared to Node.js for instance)

Comment: Swift compiles down to machine code in exactly the same way that C does, so theoretically there is no performance difference between C and Swift, depending on how you write your code. I would be interested to see where you are getting the high latency results from compared to Node, especially given 3 hasn't really been benchmarked correctly.

Comment: @hans I don't think it's fair to say Vapor 3.0 has a high latency compared to NodeJS. In my benchmarks thus far, NodeJS had a 17MB memory overhead, 45K requests/second and a 2.4ms response time with stdev of 6ms.

Vapor 3 on the other hand has a 5MB memory overhead, 80k requests/second and a 0.89ms response time with a 0.2ms standard deviation.

Comment: @0xTim: Swift contains hidden facilities absent in C, which creates processing overhead in the code compiled therefrom, which sometimes can be avoided in C. In C these things have to be handled by the programmer, in Swift the compiler takes care of it, not always in the most efficient manner.

Comment: @JoannisO: Thanks for these numbers. And thanks for your answers. It's interesting/useful for many people